# Problem with struct vs. NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

Another (hopefully easy) beginner's question: I tried to measure the size of an UITextView, but I got a big compiler error for the following code:

```
NSString *temp2String;
temp2String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[textView text]];

CGSize strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:@"Courier" constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

NSString *temp2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"String width: %f", strSize.width];
textViewSizeW.text = temp2;
[temp2 release];
```

The error was: Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct UIFont *'when passing argument 1 of sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' from distinct Objective-C type".

I'm afraid but this sounds like goobledigook to me. Have I messed up Strings and Structs? I tried to be so careful not to mix them this time (I got it wrong earlier on... see my earlier post).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain english, the error is "argument 1 of X method is an NSString object, expected a UIFont object".

So, the correct code is:

```
UIFont *strFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:12];
CGSize strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:strFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I like your plain english - perhaps you should try and apply to be xCodes new compiler and debugger... :) I like your translation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the sizeWithFont: method with a paramater of *NSString type* "Courier".  You need to instantiate a UIFont object using `[UIFont fontWithName:@"CourierBlah" size:12.0` and pass *the UIFont Object* as the paramater.

Answer (score 0):

goobledigook? It's pretty clear what went wrong.

you passed a struct NSString (@"Courier") but the method expected a struct UIFont.

I guess this is still the textview problem. so pass the font of the textview.

```
CGSize strSize = [temp2String sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000)
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: sorry, it's getting late, I think I should call it a day. You're right, it's pretty clear. But sometimes everything seems so wired... especially if you tried to look for a solution for 45 minutes. Thanks for your patience, though!

Comment: no need to apologize. But this is one of the most clear compiler message you'll see in your life.